# C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QPushButton' with cmake and qt

Tags: qt, visual-c++, cmake

My cmake:

```
set(QT_VERSION_REQ "5.11.0")
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick Widgets REQUIRED)
```

My includes:

```
#include <QGuiApplication> //ok
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine> //ok
#include <QPushButton> // <<==  fails!!
```

What am I missing in my cmake?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the precise text of both the error message and the command that failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to add QT Widgets this way:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)  
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick Qt5::Widgets ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```